# BHO developer licence - unkown publisher

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

I have developed a BHO for Internet Explorer and it can be installed successfully by users.

However, when users install the BHO they are presented with a dialog which declares then the add on is from an 'unknown' publisher.

Is it possible to become a 'known' or registered developer of BHO's? If so how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Comment: @durron597 I disagree, this question is about signing an installer, so the installation will display the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to digitally sign your BHO (and its installer). This also enables you to develop reputation for SmartScreen.

The process isn't overly difficult, but it can seem so due to the number of details.  @EricLaw has a [nice introduction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/22/authenticode-code-signing-for-developers-for-file-downloads-building-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx) to the process and the reasoning.

The current version of the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx) is slightly dated, but contains a fair amount of background that can fill in some of the blanks.

An [older blog](https://gregorbowie.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/digital-signing-of-activex-controls/) post offers some direct tips that seem relevant.

Be aware that ActiveX extensions are a legacy technology that will not be supported in Microsoft Edge (formerly known as Project Spartan), the browser that [replaces IE in Windows 10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx).

Hope this helps.